# Iterate Using .bxp() to Match Colors of other Axes

Tags: matplotlib, boxplot, axis, multiple-axes

Here is my problem:
[image]
I want the colors of the boxplots to match the histogram colors.

In previous paired plots I iterate over datasets and when in the same loop `Matplotlib` handles colors for me.  `ax.bxp()` [(documentation)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-bxp) works differently than other plotting functions, taking a list of dictionaries so iterating is not necessary.

```
        ax.bxp(list_of_dicts # from my DataFrame below
                ,vert=False
                ,showfliers=False)
```

When I iterate through the boxplot DataFrame rows and use `ax.bxp()` the boxplots are plotted on top of one another making it useless.

What should I try next?

Sample data for creating the `ax.bxp()` plot:

```
       q1     med      mean      q3  whishi  whislo my_data_col label
0  73.992  74.000  73.99936  74.006  73.982  74.030        obs1  obs1
1  73.995  74.001  73.99996  74.007  73.967  74.024        obs2  obs2
2  73.993  73.998  74.00100  74.009  73.986  74.021        obs3  obs3
3  73.999  74.005  74.00332  74.007  73.985  74.020        obs4  obs4
4  73.996  74.004  74.00224  74.009  73.984  74.014        obs5  obs5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the colors explicitly, so you can reuse them across the histograms and boxplots.

Below is an example how you could use the batched `ax.bxp()` and set colors.

If you managed to do it in a for loop but are just stuck with the boxes overlapping, then look into the `positions` arg of `ax.bxp()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

# fake data
np.random.seed(19680801)
data = np.random.lognormal(size=(37, 4), mean=1.5, sigma=1.75)
labels = list("ABCD")

# compute the boxplot stats
stats = cbook.boxplot_stats(data, labels=labels, bootstrap=10000)
for n in range(len(stats)):
    stats[n]["med"] = np.median(data)
    stats[n]["mean"] *= 2

# draw boxplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bplots = ax.bxp(stats, patch_artist=True)
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.set_yticklabels([])

# change colors
colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "orange"]
for patch, clr in zip(bplots["boxes"], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(clr)

plt.show()
```

[image: colored boxes]

Comment: used your recommendations and largely works.  However, the box part of my boxplots have been shrunk to ~1/2 the width of the original posting.  Any suggestions on that?  My best guess is the `positions` parameter somehow played a role - but it's a guess.

Comment: Look into the `widths` arg then, the documentation said that it defaults to `clip(0.15*(distance between extreme positions), 0.15, 0.5)`, so yes the `positions` arg does play a role. I think you can get the positions you used before with something like `bplots["whiskers"][i].get_ydata()` (two whiskers/lines per box).